# Angular2 : inputs focus

Tags: angular

I'm new on angular 2 and have a problem with my code.
I'm trying to change input1 focus on my input2 when the maxlength is reach. 
For now, I count the number of pressed keys and compare to the maxlength.
I don't understand how use the .focus property ...
I have try the directives but I failled again, I dont'have no others ideas to solve this problem ... It makes me crazy !
Can someone help me plz ?

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-about',
  template: ` 
   <span (ngSubmit)="onMovieSubmit()" *ngFor="let MovieField of MovieTab">
    <input 
      type="text" 
      maxlength="6"
      size="3"
      #movieName 
      (keyup)= presskeyNumber(movieName.value.length,MovieField.length,MovieField.id)><br/>
   </span>
   `
})

export class AboutComponent {
  @Output() RestrictionNumber:number;

  public presskeyNumber(movieName: any, restriction: number, MovieField: number) {
    this.RestrictionNumber = restriction;
    if (movieName === this.RestrictionNumber) {     // If my movie field length = my maxlength
      console.log('fieldFocus : ', MovieField + 1); // The next input Id
      // Change focus here
    }
  }

  public MovieTab = [
    { id: 1, movieName: "Movie1", length: 6 },
    { id: 2, movieName: "Movie2", length: 6 },
    { id: 3, movieName: "Movie3", length: 6 }
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ViewChild('movieName') movieName


public presskeyNumber(movieName: any, restriction: number, MovieField: number) {
    this.RestrictionNumber = restriction;
    if (movieName === this.RestrictionNumber) {     // If my movie field length = my maxlength
      console.log('fieldFocus : ', MovieField + 1); // The next input Id
      // Change focus here
       this.movieName.nativeElement.focus()
    }
  }
```

If you want to use it inside a loop, maybe it's even easier to pass the local variable as an argument to your method :

```
<span (ngSubmit)="onMovieSubmit()" *ngFor="let MovieField of MovieTab">
    <input 
      type="text" 
      maxlength="6"
      size="3"
      #movieName 
      (keyup)= presskeyNumber(movieName, movieName.value.length,MovieField.length,MovieField.id)><br/>
   </span>
```

And then :

```
public presskeyNumber(movieNameElement, movieName: any, restriction: number, MovieField: number) {
    this.RestrictionNumber = restriction;
    if (movieName === this.RestrictionNumber) {     // If my movie field length = my maxlength
      console.log('fieldFocus : ', MovieField + 1); // The next input Id
      // Change focus here
       movieNameElement.focus()
    }
  }
```

This way, you don't need to use `ViewChild` because you're passing the input element to your function.

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Hi guys, thx for yours answers and comments !
If I understand the syntax, the ViewChild decorator take a local variable (#movieName) in his parameters and the movieName is a new variable used to do the nativeElement.focus, right ?
But does this method works with more 2 inputs (because of local variable and my *ngFor loop) ?

Is it possible to do this ? 
focus on input1 -> focus on input2 -> focus on input3